# Relation between sum of squared norm and squared norm of sum of vectors?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there a relation between
$||\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf x_i||^2$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n||\mathbf x_i||^2$ where each $\mathbf x_i \in R^N$, and $||\cdot||$ is $L_2$ norm?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the $x_i$ are orthogonal, the two terms are equal. In the general case,

$$||\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf x_i||^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n||\mathbf x_i||^2 + \sum_{i\neq j}x_i.x_j$$

**Proof** :

$$||\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf x_i||^2 = (\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf x_i)(\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf x_i) = \sum_{i=1}^nx_i.x_i + \sum_{i\neq j}x_i.x_j = \sum_{i=1}^n||\mathbf x_i||^2 + \sum_{i\neq j}x_i.x_j$$

We have also an inequality, which could be obtained by applying $n$ times Cauchy-Schwarz inequality :

$$||\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf x_i||^2 = (x_{11} + ... + x_{n1})^2 + ... + (x_{1n} + ... + x_{nn})^2$$

$$||\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf x_i||^2\leqslant n (x_{11}^2 + ... + x_{n1}^2) + ... + n (x_{1n}^2 + ... + x_{nn}^2)$$

$$||\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf x_i||^2\leqslant n \sum_{i=1}^n||\mathbf x_i||^2$$

Comment: So there is no relation like greater or less, because last term can be ether positive or negative.

Comment: I've updated my answer, there is a relation like less, but with a $n$ !

Comment: I am not sure that I understand how Cauchy-Schwarz is applied. 1 in your equation represent scalar not vector? I am not sure that we can apply this inequality with vector and scalar.

Comment: Yes, I'm wrong. I've changed the answer : we have, however, the same inequality than before.

Comment: Now, I understand. Thank you for answer.

Comment: What is this property called? Especially for 2 vectors, we can prove this with Pythagoras thm too, right?

Comment: Late hi:) Can you please explain where the norm gone on the first equation in the first line of the proof?